# Why does the compiler skip my while statement?

Tags: c++, loops, while-loop, logic

This is a simple and silly loop exercise I've developed for practice in C++.

Issue here is when I manually enter 'h' in the terminal, I'm expecting to see the output I've constructed in the `if` loop. However, the terminal returns the 
`while` loop instead. I suspect it is because I have misused the data type, though I'm unsure.

Here's what I have written:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() { 

char letter;
int attempts = 0;
char h;

cout << "Welcome user.\n\n";
cout << "Before we begin,\n";
cout << "might I ask what your favorite letter is?\n";
cout << "For arbitrary reasons only.\n\n";
cin >> letter;




  while (letter !=h && attempts <= 2) {
      cout << "That is a sad letter\n";
      cout << "and not the kind of letter we're looking for here.\n";
      cout << "Please choose another.\n\n";
      cin >> letter;
      attempts++;
  }

  if (letter == h) {
      cout << "Ah, what a wonderful letter.\n";
      cout << "Let us continue on and not worry ourselves with such trivial matters\n";
  }

}
```

Comment: You are using a variable named h. What is the value for h?

Comment: That's the thing. 
I am trying to say 'h' would be the "correct" favorite letter. 
So consequently I believe the value of 'h' would be 0 or itself, if that makes sense.

Comment: It's an indeterminate garbage value in your variable `h`. Using it makes your code have undefined behavior.

Comment: The variable named `h` is different from the character `'h'`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to either put single quotation marks around 'h' in your while loop and if statement or assign 'h' to your variable (char h = 'h'). Only do one of these though, not both or they will cancel each other out.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You need to give a value to h for this to work. eg char h = 'h';